# find and replace from other tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to replace student email addresses with their plain text names. I have compiled all of the active student names and emails in another tab.

How would I go about searching 'SHEET2:A' (the entries) and adding to a new column everywhere it matches 'SHEET1:E' (email reference sheet) their name 'SHEET1:D' (name+ID)

Example Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AGqBXCxWwWR2DnsagaxZJXeNg_KsJ7B26_MWyedqg84/edit?usp=sharing

If it would make it easier, I could move the reference section to SHEET2 in another column or way down in the rows. The entries will be random and will consist of multiple duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` is your friend:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!D:D}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

or if you want to put it in **B1** cell:

```
={"First Last  -  ID"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!D:D}, 2, 0)))}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!D:D}, 2, 0)))
```